# ibm watson document classification

Tags: classification, document, watson

I want to classify documents with the ibm watson api "natural language classifier" but it is limited to only 1000 characters per document, which is not sufficient for me. 
Is there another api that would work with large documents containing more than 1000 characters?

Comment: Asking for software/libraries is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

NLC is not designed for classifying documents, it's designed to classify questions and intents.

If you want to classify documents with Watson you can use the Alchemy API, Watson explorer, Watson knowledge studio or Retrieve and Rank.